# Get SQL Query from XSD File

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, xsd

I've inherited a VB.NET project with .xsd files. Is it possible/How can I get the SQL query that corresponds with the results of the .xsd file?

**Additional Info**: I'm using Visual Studio 2012. This is a Windows Form Desktop Application in .NET 4. I've never worked with a xsd file before, so I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology.

Here's what this looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess **you can't get a SQL query from an .XSD file** because XSDs are simply local DataTables.

What you can do, however, is infer from what you see. For example:

[image]

This table above is probably `SELECT * FROM Sheet3`.

[image]

And this table above is a SELECT * on three tables, inner joined by `vehicleID`

I assumed you could see a "SQL view" and "Design view" similar to how PowerBuilder works, but I guess not. Better answers and insights are appreciated.